# Excel crashing when opening file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

When trying to open an excel workbook I get the standard Microsoft Excel has stopped working... and it crashes.

If I open excel first (on a blank document) I can click on workbooks to open them or browse to them and open them.  Both work fine.

This issue occurs with both 2010 and 2013 (I have uninstalled and reinstalled both).  I have launched Excel in safe mode, ran the repair tool, etc.  Short of reformatting the machine I am all out of ideas.

If anyone has resolved this issue I would appreciate some assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: What information you have about the crash?

Comment: Have you tried re-saving the files to attempt to over-write whatever is causing the crash? Is it just a few specific files causing this or is it every file?

Comment: Did this problem appear in specific files or all Excel files? Where did you save the file? Did the file contain any macro codes?

Comment: It is any excel document not a few specific ones.  It has no macros, there are no addons.  For the crash specifically, the crash windows is generic not responding, there is a severe lack of information on why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was:

1.- I tried to remove the add-ins and did not work
2.-I started EXCEL in safe mode and then I tried to open the files I needed which luckily for me, opened up without problems.
3.- I saved them as XLSM
4.- Re-started excel in normal mode and problem solved.  Hope this helps!

I believe the files got corrupted somehow as I was using VBA for others and I might have run a global macro or something similar.